# group_concat on an empty join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, grouping

I've got the following problem:
I have two tables: (simplified)

```
+--------+    +-----------+
| User   |    | Role      |
+--------+    +-----------+
| ID<PK> |    | ID <PK>   |
+--------+    | Name      |
              +-----------+
```

and M:N relationship between them

```
+-------------+   
| User_Role   |   
+-------------+
| User<FK>    |
| Role<FK>    |
+-------------+
```

I need to create a view, which selects me: User, and in one column, all of his Roles (this is done by group_concat).

I've tried following:

```
SELECT u.*, group_concat(r.Name separator ',') as Roles FROM 
  User u
  LEFT JOIN User_Role ur ON ur.User=u.ID
  LEFT JOIN Role r ON ur.Role=r.ID
 GROUP BY u.ID;
```

However, this works for an user with *some* defined roles. Users without role aren't returned. How can I modify the statement, to return me User with empty string in Roles column when User doesn't have any Role?

Explanation: I'm passing the SQL data directly to a grid, which then formats itself, and it is easier for me to create slow and complicated view, than to format it in my code.

I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have try your `SQL` and have no pb to run it , all row are returned even user without role, the only thing that you have null into the roles column, to avoid that use `COALESCE` function to get an empty string when the field will be NULL.

```
SELECT u.*, group_concat(COALESCE(r.Name, "") separator ',') as Roles FROM 
  User u
  LEFT JOIN User_Role ur ON ur.User=u.ID
  LEFT JOIN Role r ON ur.Role=r.ID
 GROUP BY u.ID;
```

Comment: Now I look like an complete idiot :-) The second join I used was inner, but at SO I wrote it right. Thanks for coalesce, through.