# MySQL using like expression in referenced table

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

It's about searching for a keyword in a database, precisely in the table `users` while weighting the user's name and his email address differently as for the ranking/score.
 This should not be about full text search, so here is my approach:

I want to search in the entire database for the keyword 'john' and it shall also return *john*, e.g. 'johna', plus the name shall be weighted more than the email address:

```
select u.id,u.name,((u.name LIKE '%john%')*5 + (u.mail LIKE '%john%')*3) as score
from users u
having score > 0
order by score desc
```

Imagine there is a table `user_has_kittens`:

```
user_id  kitten_id
------------------
1        1
1        2
1        3
1        4
2        3
2        42
```

You already see what this table is for: It has definitions for which user has which kitten and of course you can have an arbitrary amount of them.

In addition, the kittens have names in a table `kittens` with cols  `id`,`name`

How is it possible to search for kitten names as well and weighting them like this: the keyword is in the kitten's name, then give this user a score plus 1.

Pseudo
`select [...] + SUM [ ( u's kitten's name like %john% )*1]  ) as score`

e.g. for clarification:

```
username, email,            (his/her kittens);   score
john,     john@example.org, (johna, myjohn);     5+3+1+1 (user matches, mail matches, two kittens match)
linda,    linda@john.org,   (myjohn);            0+3+1   (user doesn't match, mail matches, one kitten matches)
```

Btw. using this in doctrine is the aim, however plain native MySql is very sufficient as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your actual requirement. But I think I can direct you towards the right..

```
select u.id,u.name,( if(u.name LIKE '%john%', 5, 0) + if(u.mail LIKE '%john%', 3, 0)) as score
```

try this

Comment: This already works, please read the entire question. 
It's about also searching for the string `john` in the referenced table `kitten`.

Comment: The structure is as simple as a m2m relation can be, so it is table `users` with `id`,`name` and kittens with `id`,`name` as mentioned in the question. The referencing table is called `user_has_kittens`.
I guess, there has to be some stacked or nested `SELECT` within the query thus looping for each user through all kittens. Maybe sth. with `Group_CONCAT`

Comment: @croma Ok check this [sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/157ba3/6)..Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks - very good but not perfect, because when some user has no kitten, he won't be displayed, even if his username matches the keyword - try removing `value (2, 1)`  @ line 34, user 'btest' has 'test' in his username but is not shown.  
  Btw. i know there exist also solutions with `LEFT JOIN` and concatenating the referenced values - here: kittens - comma separated and then check this aggreagated value, c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400498/group-concat-on-an-empty-join-in-mysql (the queston there is already working solution, btw)  
  though i prefer working on this approach

Comment: @croma. Ya I missed that situation.Thanks for remembering me.Actually the solutions is perfect way is important.Hope you find that.